# ¿Cómo hacer que una lista desplegable Select option sea consultada por la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, estoy haciendo un formulario que ya puede registrar datos (contiene diferentes inputs), entre ellos esta la lista desplegable Select en la cual tengo varios option; el problema llega al momento de hacer la consulta a la base de datos ya que no me lo reconoce.

Este es el código

```
      <select class="select" name="Num_Equipo" required="required"> 
         <option value=""></option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="1">Equipo 1</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="2">Equipo 2</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="3">Equipo 3</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="4">Equipo 4</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="5">Equipo 5</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="6">Equipo 6</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="7">Equipo 7</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="8">Equipo 8</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="9">Equipo 9</option>
         <option name="Num_Equipo" value="10">Equipo 10</option>
      <select>

<input type="submit" value="Consultarr" name="btn-consultar"/>
```

Este el PHP

```
$basededatos = "formularioest";

$tabla = "info";

if(isset($_POST['btn-consultar']))
{

  include("abrir_conexion.php");
    
    $Num_Equipo = $_POST['Num_Equipo'];

    $resultados = mysqli_query($enlace,"SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE Num_Equipo = $Num_Equipo");
    while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
    {
      echo
      "
      
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class=\"td1\"><b><center>Fecha</center></b></td>
          <td class=\"td1\"><b><center>Estado</center></b></td>
          <td class=\"td1\"><b><center>Num_Equipo</center></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><center>".$consulta['Fecha']."</center></td>
          <td><center>".$consulta['Estado']."</center></td>
          <td><center>".$consulta['Num_Equipo']."</center></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      ";
```

He intentado hacer la consulta de igual forma como si fuera un input de texto pero no me sale nada, de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Estás sobreescribiendo el atributo `name` del `select` en cada una de las `option`, ver [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) para aprender a construir un **select/option(s)** correctamente.

Comment: Como bien dice @aeportugal, el `name`, en el caso de `select ... option` se pone **una sola vez** y se le asigna al `select`, como ya lo tienes. Por otra parte, no vemos si eso está dentro de un `form`¿? Si no es un `form` los datos no se enviarán, aunque lo pongas en un `input`.

Comment: todo esta dentro de un form, porque los datos se envian correctamente a la base de datos, lo unico que no hace es consultarme los datos de esta